# Why does bash eval return 0 on command exiting with status > 0?

Tags: bash, eval, exit-code

I can't get my mind around the fact that using Bash `eval` on a command execution that clearly exits with status > 0 still returns with 0. Consider this example:

```
> eval "$(exit 42)"
> echo $?
0
```

The command `$(exit 42)` alone has exit code > 0, so according to the `man` page, `eval` should return itself an exit status of `42`...

```
eval [arg ...]
    The args are read and concatenated together into a single command. This command is
    then read and executed by the shell, and its exit status is returned as the value
    of eval. If there are no args, or only null arguments, eval returns 0.
```

What do I misunderstand?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414761/62174

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading again the question and the extract from manual, the argument of eval is expanded before `eval` being called.

`"$(exit 42)"` expands to empty string and command becomes `eval ''` which exits with success.

`set -x` can be used to trace what's happening

```
set -x
> eval "$(exit 42)"
++ exit 42
+ eval ''
```

however

```
> x=$(exit 42)
++ exit 42
+ x=
> echo "$?"
+ echo 42
42
```

See also that single quotes are different because expansion is processed by eval `eval '$(exit 42)'` returns 42

```
> eval '$(exit 42)'
+ eval '$(exit 42)'
+++ exit 42
```

Comment: Perhaps separately point out that `eval "exit 42"` will indeed fail as expected, and exit from the current shell.

Comment: yes, rather reading the question again the OP didn't understood that command substitution is occuring before eval being called